# Ollama not found with Quakus, forbidden with Firefox RESTED plugin

Tags: quarkus, ollama, langchain4j

I'm running Ollama in Docker.
I tried to install it as a service, the issue is the same.
I'm on Unbuntu 22.04.
I created a Quarkus project with the quarkus-langchain4j-ollama dependency.
When I run the project with mvn quarkus:dev and then hit "d", I'm on the Quarkus Dev UI.
If I go to the [chat](http://localhost:8080/q/dev-ui/io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.quarkus-langchain4j-core/chat) and ask a question, I have a 404 error.

```
"Received: 'Not Found, status code 404' when invoking: Rest Client method: 'io.quarkiverse.langchain4j.ollama.OllamaRestApi#generate'"
```

If I check the Ollama Logs, I can see a call to "/api/generate".
My Docker compose file looks like this :

```
services:
  ollama:
    image: ollama/ollama
    container_name: ollama
    volumes:
      - ~/docker/data/ollama:/root/.ollama
    ports:
      - 11434:11434
    environment:
      - OLLAMA_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - OLLAMA_ORIGINS=http://0.0.0.0:11434
```

If I try to access it with the RESTED Firefox plugin, I have a 403 : Forbidden error.
And still, I can see a call to "/api/generate" in the Ollama logs.
And if I run the following curl, it works perfectly :

> curl -X POST http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{   "model":
> "mistral",   "prompt":"Tell me a joke"  }'

Note : If I update OLLAMA_ORIGINS to Resteasy Reactive Client then the Quarkus error turns to

```
"io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connexion refusée: localhost/127.0.0.1:11434"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, on the Quarkus side, it was all caused by a typo : in my application.properties, I typed

> quarkus.langchain4j.ollama.chat-model.model-id=mistral:lastest

with an extra in latest.

With

> quarkus.langchain4j.ollama.chat-model.model-id=mistral:latest

it works perfectly.
It's strange that the error was a 404 with no more explainations.

On the Firefox plugin, it was fixed by adding and environment to the docker compose : `OLLAMA_ORIGINS=moz-extension://*` or on a larger scale : `OLLAMA_ORIGINS=*`

Answer (score 1):

The DNS name of Ollama in the compose stack is the name of the service.
So you should use these environment variables:

```
    environment:
      - OLLAMA_HOST=ollama
      - OLLAMA_ORIGINS=http://ollama:11434
```

Of course, you need to pull the model to be able to query Ollama. Or you can create an image with the preloaded model: https://github.com/whales-demos/llm-in-container/blob/main/ollama-04/Dockerfile

If you have an issue with the volume, try this:

```
    volumes:
      - ./ollama:/root/.ollama
```